# How to set an "environment" in a non-trivial way using expression?

Tags: github-actions, credentials, github-secret

I have a GitHub Actions workflow which deploys some things to an environment. The workflow needs to log in to access the environment, so we use GitHub environment secrets to store credentials.

My workflow contains this:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      deployment_target:
        type: choice
        description: Choose an environment to deploy to
        options:
          - dev
          - staging
          - production
          - benchmarks
...
jobs:
  deploy-to-persistent-environment:
    environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.deployment_target}}
    steps: 
      - name: Login # Pseudocode
        run: login -password "${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}"
      - name: Deploy # Pseudocode
        run: DeploymentTool.exe -environment "${{ github.event.inputs.deployment_target}}"
```

The "benchmarks" environment uses the same credentials as the "development" environment. So I would like to re-use the same GitHub environment secrets rather than have two sets of duplicate environment secrets in GitHub.

I.e., I would like to do something like this pseudocode:

```
jobs:
  deploy-to-persistent-environment: # Pseudocode
    environment: ${{ if github.event.inputs.deployment_target == 'benchmarks' then 'development' else github.event.inputs.deployment_target }}
    steps: 
      - name: Login
        run: login -password "${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}"
      - name: Deploy
        run: DeploymentTool.exe -environment "${{ github.event.inputs.deployment_target}}"
```

Is there any way to achieve this with GitHub Actions?

Comment: It seems [there is a way](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/409#issuecomment-752775072) to do it directly using an expression: `environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.deployment_target == 'benchmarks' && 'development' ||  github.event.inputs.deployment_target }}`. Could you try it and inform if it works? (I would then give a more advance explanation as answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it directly in the expression, according to [this reference on the Github Community](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/409#issuecomment-752775072), by using the syntax `${{ x && 'ifTrue' || 'ifFalse'  }}`

In that case:

- if the condition `x` is True, the `first` argument will be used.
- if the condition `x` is False, the `second` argument will be used.

In our case here, it would look like this:

```yaml
environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.deployment_target == 'benchmarks' && 'development' ||  github.event.inputs.deployment_target }}
```

Where:

- if `github.event.inputs.deployment_target == 'benchmarks'` is True, `development` will be used as environment.
- if `github.event.inputs.deployment_target == 'benchmarks'` is False, `github.event.inputs.deployment_target` will be used as environment.

Updating the pseudocode:

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy-to-persistent-environment: # Pseudocode
    environment: ${{ github.event.inputs.deployment_target == 'benchmarks' && 'development' ||  github.event.inputs.deployment_target }}   
    steps: 
      - name: Login
        run: login -password "${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}"
      - name: Deploy
        run: DeploymentTool.exe -environment "${{ github.event.inputs.deployment_target}}"
```

*EDIT: This is now available on [the GitHub official doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example) as well (Thanks [Benjamin W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) for reporting)*

Comment: This has by now made its way into the [official docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example), too.